# Change a for loop to execute functions on one row at a time

Tags: jquery, loops, jsonp, datatables

I have a function that is to run through each row of a table, grab the number from that cell, send that number to a url to fetch a json response, then print something based on that.  I almost have it working but as it is now it is just dumping these all out at once, I want it to use something like `.each` to go through each row, do its stuff then move to the next.  I am also working with jquery datatables.  The script is like this :

```
$j('#imageCheck').click(function(){
    var cells = [];
    var rows = oTable.fnGetNodes();
    for( var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
        grabsku = $j(rows[i]).find('td:eq(2)').text();
        imgreplace = $j(rows[i]).find('td:eq(2)');
        s7url = 'http://checkit.com/is/image/' + grabsku;       

        $j.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: s7url,
            data: 'req=exists,json',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            beforeSend:function(){
                imgreplace.html('checking ..');
            },
            success: function(){
                imgreplace.html(z);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The response and everything works fine, my question is how to loop these one by one. So as in this example the `imgreplace.html('checking ..');` happens simultaneously through every row in the table.  I want it to just process that one row and after `success` move on to the next.

### Update

To better explain why I am doing it this way, I agree it is unnatural, the data I grabbing from each cell helps form a unique url, `s7url`.  Each of these returns a response like this from a server I have no control over:

```
s7jsonResponse(
{"catalogRecord.exists":"0"},"");
```

I then do something with knowing if true or false like this :

```
function jsonResponse(response){    
    x = response["record.exists"];  
    z = x == "0" ? "NO" : "YES";
}
```

I like scrappedcola's solution but it led me to discover that the success is never being fired.  I am not sure why that is.  I can see in the inspector tab that there is a response like I pasted above.  I tried to move the success into its own function, something like :

```
success: function(){ success(); } 

...

var success = function(){
    imgreplace.html(z);
    i++;
    handleImageCheck(i);    
}
```

but that didnt help..

### Update 2

So I gave up trying to put the variables into success.  Instead I will share with you my very ugly hack.  On success of the error response, ick.

```
error: function(data, status){
        if (status = "parseerror") {
            imgreplace.html(z);
            i++;
            handleImageCheck(i);    
        }
    }
```

### Update 3

If for some reason anybody cares, I found the solution for my other problem of `success` not firing.  I needed to add `jsonpCallback` to the options and then process the response as a function in the `succcess`.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how ajax works. Ajax is asynchronous(http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/asynchronous?s=t) So when you make the ajax call as above it sends out the request and then continues on with the iteration through the table. A better approach might be to loop through each row and gather the values you need and then send all of the data at once to the server and act upon it that way (it would also make it go a bit faster). The fewer times you have to interact with the DOM the better for your application

Comment: Thanks scrappedcola, I normally would not do it this way but in this case the `s7url` will be different url for each request.  The response is binary and I have to do something with that depending on whether it is true or false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something similar to this might work for you. Basically you should make 1 call to the image check function that makes the async call. Then upon success of the async call go to the next row.

```
var i;  
  $j('#imageCheck').click(function(){ 
     i = 0;
     handleImageCheck(i);
  })
  var handleImageCheck = function(i){
     var cells = [];
     var rows = oTable.fnGetNodes();
     if($j(rows[i]).length)
     {     
    grabsku = $j(rows[i]).find('td:eq(2)').text();
    imgreplace = $j(rows[i]).find('td:eq(2)');
    s7url = 'http://checkit.com/is/image/' + grabsku;       

    $j.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
       url: s7url,
       data: 'req=exists,json',
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       beforeSend:function(){
          imgreplace.html('checking ..');
       },
       success: function(){
          imgreplace.html(z);
          i++;
          handleImageCheck(i);
       }
     });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want you should use a little recursion

```
function makeCall(rows, index) {
    //if index is undefined, it's the first call, let's start from the first element
    if (index === undefined) {
        index = 0;
    }
    row = rows[index];
    grabsku = $j(row).find('td:eq(2)').text();
    imgreplace = $j(row).find('td:eq(2)');
    s7url = 'http://checkit.com/is/image/' + grabsku;

    $j.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: s7url,
        data: 'req=exists,json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        beforeSend: function() {
            imgreplace.html('checking ..');
            var nextIndex = index + 1;
            //if there is anothe element in rows, make another call)
            if (rows[nextIndex] !== undefined) {
                makeCall(rows, nextIndex);
            }
        },
        success: function() {
            imgreplace.html(z);
        }
    });
}

       var rows = oTable.fnGetNodes();
       makeCall(rows);
```

BTW - AJAX is cool because you can make a lot of calls at once, waiting like this seems not natural to me!